# Templating return types

Tags: c#, templates, http-post

I'm trying to make this return a templated object which is a different type that what is sent. How do I do it?

````
  UserSSS user = new UserSSS();

 ReturnObject foo = await _callServer.PostAsync($"{Constants.SERVER_URL}/profiles/v1/HelloObject", user);

       public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url, T toPost)
        {
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

#if DEBUG
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
#endif
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toPost);
            StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                var ret = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
                string contents = await ret.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents);
            }
        }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean different generic input and output types? If yes then it's simple as:

```
public async Task<TOut> PostAsync<TIn, TOut>(string url, TIn toPost)
```

and in the return

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOut>(contents);
```